# html sidebar centered image footer

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I am making a new sidebar for my website, if you view the bellow code snippet in a full window you can see the 'sideBarFooter' element (which contains the image and some text below it).

I'm trying to get this footer to always be at the bottom of the sidebar, ive tried adding margin-top and margin-bottom styling but with no luck. How can I align my sideBarFooter to be at the bottom of my sidebar element ?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#sidebarCollapse').on('click', function() {
    $('#sidebar').toggleClass('active');
  });
});
```

```css
@import "https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:300,400,500,600,700";
body {
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  background: #ffffff;
}

p {
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.1em;
  font-weight: 300;
  line-height: 1.7em;
  color: #999;
}

.btn-info {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #b81717;
  border-color: #52b817;
}

a,
a:hover,
a:focus {
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}

.navbar {
  padding: 15px 10px;
  background: #fff;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 0;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.navbar-btn {
  box-shadow: none;
  outline: none !important;
  border: none;
}

.line {
  width: 100%;
  height: 1px;
  border-bottom: 1px dashed #ddd;
  margin: 40px 0;
}


/* ---------------------------------------------------
        SIDEBAR STYLE
    ----------------------------------------------------- */

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  align-items: stretch;
}

#sidebar {
  min-width: 250px;
  max-width: 250px;
  background: #f7f9fb;
  /* NAVBAR BACKGROUND */
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  transition: all 0.3s;
}

#sidebar.active {
  margin-left: -250px;
}

#sidebar .sidebar-header {
  padding: 20px;
  /* background: #6d7fcc; */
}

#sidebar ul.components {
  /* padding: 20px 0; */
  /* border-bottom: 1px solid #47748b; */
}

#sidebar ul p {
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
}

#sidebar ul li a {
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 1.1em;
  display: block;
}

.currentPage,
.currentPage * {
  background: #bed6b8 !important;
}

#sidebar ul li a:hover {
  color: #000;
  background: #8FC1E3;
  /* hover tab color */
}

#sidebar ul li.active>a,
a[aria-expanded="true"] {
  /* color: #fff; */
  background: #f7f9fb;
  /* active tab */
}

a[data-toggle="collapse"] {
  position: relative;
}

.dropdown-toggle::after {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 20px;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

ul ul a {
  font-size: 0.9em !important;
  padding-left: 30px !important;
  background: #f7f9fb;
  /* tab list color */
}

ul.CTAs {
  padding: 20px;
}

ul.CTAs a {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 0.9em !important;
  display: block;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}


/* ---------------------------------------------------
        CONTENT STYLE
    ----------------------------------------------------- */

#content {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 20px;
  min-height: 100vh;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}


/* ---------------------------------------------------
        MEDIAQUERIES
    ----------------------------------------------------- */

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  #sidebar {
    margin-left: -250px;
  }
  #sidebar.active {
    margin-left: 0;
  }
  #sidebarCollapse span {
    color: pink display: inline;
  }
}


/* Sidebar expand/collapse button */

#sidebutton {
  margin-left: 100%;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 4px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
  border: none;
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#sideBarFooter{
}
```

```html
<!-- jQuery CDN - Slim version (=without AJAX) -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<!-- Popper.JS -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-cs/chFZiN24E4KMATLdqdvsezGxaGsi4hLGOzlXwp5UZB1LY//20VyM2taTB4QvJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<!-- Bootstrap JS -->
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-uefMccjFJAIv6A+rW+L4AHf99KvxDjWSu1z9VI8SKNVmz4sk7buKt/6v9KI65qnm" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<!-- bootstrap css-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- jQuery -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Page Content -->
<div class="wrapper" class="toggled">
  <!-- Sidebar  -->
  <nav id="sidebar">

    <div class="sidebar-header">
      <h3>Website Title</h3> <button id='sidebutton'>M</button>
    </div>

    <ul class="list-unstyled components">
      <li class="currentPage">
        <a href="#">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">About</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#contactSubmenu" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="true" class="dropdown-toggle">Contact</a>
        <ul class="collapse list-unstyled" id="contactSubmenu">
          <li>
            <a href="#">Email</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Github</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">LinkedIn</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Resume</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>

    <!-- Footer -->
    <div id='sideBarFooter' class="sidebar-footer">
      <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/images/w3schools_green.jpg" alt="W3Schools.com">
      <p>Color 1: #657856</p>
      <p>Color 2: #657856</p>
      <p>Color 3: #657856</p>
    </div>

  </nav>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

A couple things:

## `height: 100vh`

First of all, the element's parent (in this case `#sidebar`) should have a height of 100% of the viewport. What's `vh` you ask? More on that [here](https://css-tricks.com/fun-viewport-units/).

## `position: absolute`, `bottom: 0`

Now you can go with a `position: absolute` and `bottom: 0`. This brings said footer to the bottom of the page.

## Why the first step?

In reality this would work without the first step, but then the `#sidebar` would not go from top to bottom, therefore affecting the gray background.

```
#sidebar {
  /* etc... */
  height: 100vh
}
```

```
#sideBarFooter{
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0
}
```

[Working Example](https://codepen.io/Bobbay/full/oNbyrQq)

Happy hacking, Bobbbay

P.S. don't use `id`s with CSS. It's a bad practice.

Answer (score 0):

You could add `display: flex` and `flex-direction: column` and a set height like `height: 100vh` to your nav element with the id sidebar. Then you just need to give the footer `margin-top: auto` and it will socially distance itself from the other elements.

Quick tip: don't style things by their ID, it's bad practice. Here's some [other rules](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/MDN/Contribute/Guidelines/Code_guidelines/CSS) MDN uses for their CSS I found it helpful.

Comment: OP, this is actually a good way to do it, but maybe learn about `flex` **after** you learn about `position: absolute` :) no offense, of course, but I didn't learn flex at the beginning either :) (unless I just had a horrible education in CSS )

Comment: @Bobbay there are several problems with position: absolute for this specific case mostly related to smaller screens. So, learning flex nowadays is a must as ir solves many situations that require hacks or fixes using older techniques.

Comment: @MihailMinkov yes you're definitely right in that way, but the way I learnt it was absolute, then flex. Of course, that was years ago, and flex was still an unsupported experimental who-knows-what. I'm not very familiarly versed with how/ **when** people __should__ learn nowadays, so I wouldn't be surprised if I was wrong :)

Edit: **bold** issues

Comment: Yes, same thing happens to me from time to time, a year ago I probably would have recommended `position: absolute` also, but since getting to know `flex` and the use of auto margin in every possible direction, it's a gem :D

Answer (score 0):

Using your example as base you just need to add a few styles and you're good to go.

What I did:

1. `body` and `html` have `height: 100%;`
2. `.wrapper` has `height: 100%`
3. `#sidebar` has `display: flex;` and `flex-direction: column;` this makes it go vertical.
4. `#sideBarFooter` has `margin-top: auto`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#sidebarCollapse').on('click', function() {
    $('#sidebar').toggleClass('active');
  });
});
```

```css
@import "https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:300,400,500,600,700";
body {
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  background: #ffffff;
}

p {
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.1em;
  font-weight: 300;
  line-height: 1.7em;
  color: #999;
}

.btn-info {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #b81717;
  border-color: #52b817;
}

a,
a:hover,
a:focus {
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}

.navbar {
  padding: 15px 10px;
  background: #fff;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 0;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.navbar-btn {
  box-shadow: none;
  outline: none !important;
  border: none;
}

.line {
  width: 100%;
  height: 1px;
  border-bottom: 1px dashed #ddd;
  margin: 40px 0;
}

body, 
html {
  height: 100%;
}


/* ---------------------------------------------------
        SIDEBAR STYLE
    ----------------------------------------------------- */

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  align-items: stretch;
  height: 100%;
}

#sidebar {
  min-width: 250px;
  max-width: 250px;
  background: #f7f9fb;
  /* NAVBAR BACKGROUND */
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  transition: all 0.3s;
  
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  
}

#sidebar.active {
  margin-left: -250px;
}

#sidebar .sidebar-header {
  padding: 20px;
  /* background: #6d7fcc; */
}

#sidebar ul.components {
  /* padding: 20px 0; */
  /* border-bottom: 1px solid #47748b; */
}

#sidebar ul p {
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
}

#sidebar ul li a {
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 1.1em;
  display: block;
}

.currentPage,
.currentPage * {
  background: #bed6b8 !important;
}

#sidebar ul li a:hover {
  color: #000;
  background: #8FC1E3;
  /* hover tab color */
}

#sidebar ul li.active>a,
a[aria-expanded="true"] {
  /* color: #fff; */
  background: #f7f9fb;
  /* active tab */
}

a[data-toggle="collapse"] {
  position: relative;
}

.dropdown-toggle::after {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 20px;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

ul ul a {
  font-size: 0.9em !important;
  padding-left: 30px !important;
  background: #f7f9fb;
  /* tab list color */
}

ul.CTAs {
  padding: 20px;
}

ul.CTAs a {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 0.9em !important;
  display: block;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}


/* ---------------------------------------------------
        CONTENT STYLE
    ----------------------------------------------------- */

#content {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 20px;
  min-height: 100vh;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}


/* ---------------------------------------------------
        MEDIAQUERIES
    ----------------------------------------------------- */

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  #sidebar {
    margin-left: -250px;
  }
  #sidebar.active {
    margin-left: 0;
  }
  #sidebarCollapse span {
    color: pink display: inline;
  }
}


/* Sidebar expand/collapse button */

#sidebutton {
  margin-left: 100%;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 4px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
  border: none;
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#sideBarFooter{
  margin-top: auto;
}
```

```html
<!-- jQuery CDN - Slim version (=without AJAX) -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<!-- Popper.JS -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-cs/chFZiN24E4KMATLdqdvsezGxaGsi4hLGOzlXwp5UZB1LY//20VyM2taTB4QvJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<!-- Bootstrap JS -->
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-uefMccjFJAIv6A+rW+L4AHf99KvxDjWSu1z9VI8SKNVmz4sk7buKt/6v9KI65qnm" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<!-- bootstrap css-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- jQuery -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Page Content -->
<div class="wrapper" class="toggled">
  <!-- Sidebar  -->
  <nav id="sidebar">

    <div class="sidebar-header">
      <h3>Website Title</h3> <button id='sidebutton'>M</button>
    </div>

    <ul class="list-unstyled components">
      <li class="currentPage">
        <a href="#">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">About</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#contactSubmenu" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="true" class="dropdown-toggle">Contact</a>
        <ul class="collapse list-unstyled" id="contactSubmenu">
          <li>
            <a href="#">Email</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Github</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">LinkedIn</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Resume</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>

    <!-- Footer -->
    <div id='sideBarFooter' class="sidebar-footer">
      <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/images/w3schools_green.jpg" alt="W3Schools.com">
      <p>Color 1: #657856</p>
      <p>Color 2: #657856</p>
      <p>Color 3: #657856</p>
    </div>

  </nav>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You should try to position your sidebar footer to absolute.
Try adding this to your css :

```
#sideBarFooter{
  position:absolute;
  bottom : 0;
}
```